# Model method dont see variable from another model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've code like this:

```
def method1
  pr_body = String.new

  @xml.weryfikacja(ktora)
  @list.each_slice(2) do |bod|
  # rest of the code   
end
```

And

```
def method2
    @list= Array.new
    @list.push(1)
end
```

Now, the error is that, in `method1`, after executing `method2`, I still can't use `@list`. If I don't want to get errors, I need to return that array from `method2`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where did you execute `method2` in `method1`?

Comment: Make a class around the functions or declare `@list` globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code shown in OP. Being called *after* `method2` *on the same instance of this class*, the `method1` will have an access to `@list` instance variable. There is probably other problem with the code, e.g. `@xml` is not defined anywhere and *it* fails / raises an exception.

Proof:

```
▶ class A
▷   def a1 ; puts @a ; end
▷   def a2 ; @a = 42 ; end
▷ end
▶ a = A.new
#⇒ #<A:0x000000026d2908>
▶ a.a2
#⇒ 42
▶ a.a1
#⇒ 42
```

Comment: My fault. My answer is wrong. But I'm not allowed to delete an accepted answer.

Comment: @BilalMaqsood It’s OK, I have removed all my comments. Let these two answers coexist together :)

Comment: Thank you for your courtesy. Ah! I've always been understanding it the way I explained in my answer earlier.

Comment: @BilalMaqsood He who makes no mistakes makes nothing :)